# How to change wrong /missing exif data for many images at once?

Tags: windows, images, exif, date-modified

First up: I'm using Windows 8.1 (Actually W10 TP, but it's close enough to 8.1).

I have roughly 32,000 pictures that I've taken over the last 7 years which 'mostly' have correct exif data.

Unfortunately when recently using some software to automatically sort these files into folders; I found out that at least 9,000 of these pictures have wrong or missing exif information for date-taken and/or date-created.

When right clicking on a file and loading properties / details tab, it looks like the "Date Modified" date and time is always (99% of the time) correct. (I'm willing to forgo correct info on that 1%)

Is there a way to automatically edit the "date-taken" and "date-created" information to reflect the "date-modified" information, without going through all 9,000 files individually and doing it myself?

Some pictures which have date taken information have incorrect modified information, so some way to skip images that already have correct "date taken" would also be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify how any automated process can know what date is correct?

Answer (score 3):

exiftool.exe "-CreateDate>DateTimeOriginal" *.jpg

[related post](http://www.martinbuitelaar.com/2009/03/08/copy-filedate-to-exif/)

[download exiftool.exe](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

Comment: None of my images appear to have "DateTimeOriginal" as a value / property. exiftool is unable to lookup or set this value. :S

Comment: alternatively you could try out with AllDates: exiftool.exe "-CreateDate>AllDates" *.jpg

Comment: If some are .jpg and some are .png (etc) do I just have to run the command multiple times / for each extension? Or is there an easier way? (the folders only contain images / movies)

Comment: yes or you can run the command with \*.\* but you have to be aware that it means all type of files in that directory

Comment: Okay, thanks.
So, would this command work? : [

exiftool.exe "-CreateDate>AllDates" D:\Users\Matthew\Pictures\Test\*.jpg
]
If so, will it also include sub-folders? :)

Comment: no problem, yes, it should work but exiftool's known problems says: "In Windows, ExifTool will not process files with Unicode characters in the file name."

sub-folders will be included only if you use -r like: exiftool.exe -r "-CreateDate>AllDates" D:\Users\Matthew\Pictures\Test*.jpg

Comment: So, it won't do any with underscores or brackets? :S

Comment: I haven't tried but e.g. underscores should work

Comment: Okay, just got round to trying it. It found an image in my test folder, but it returned as "No Writable Tags" So didn't alter any information?

Comment: Are the create and/or modified file times correct? If so you could set the EXIF values from the file data, using `exiftool -DateTimeOriginal=...`. You would probably need `PowerShell` or `bash` in order to format the date/time correctly, including seconds.

Comment: Okay, I've got it all working now :D, but having problems with the .png's?